# How to run delayed jobs in production in Rails 4.2 without running rake jobs command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

In development mode, we use `rake jobs:work`. In the same way, inorder to test in the production mode, we use `RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:work`.
As entire my application is on Apache Nginx server, is there any option like any gem / code that runs background and how it is used to run the jobs without running this command?

Answer (score 1):

Delayed job is great if you don't have Redis, if you are already using Redis I would recommend Sidekiq over delayed job. The main difference is delayed job is an SQL based job worker and Sidekiq uses Redis.

Check out the [Sidekiq: Getting Started](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started) guide for more information about using Sidekiq.

---

**Delayed also comes with a script to run jobs in the background.**

From the [README: Running Jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs)

`script/delayed_job` can be used to manage a background process which will
start working off jobs.

To do so, add `gem "daemons"` to your `Gemfile` and make sure you've run `rails
generate delayed_job`.

You can then do the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Runs two workers in separate processes.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start

# Use the --pool option to specify a worker pool. You can use this option multiple times to start different numbers of workers for different queues.
# The following command will start 1 worker for the tracking queue,
# 2 workers for the mailers and tasks queues, and 2 workers for any jobs:
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=tracking --pool=mailers,tasks:2 --pool=*:2 start

# Runs all available jobs and then exits
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start --exit-on-complete
# or to run in the foreground
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run --exit-on-complete
```

**Rails 4:** *replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job*

Workers can be running on any computer, as long as they have access to the
database and their clock is in sync. Keep in mind that each worker will check
the database at least every 5 seconds.

You can also invoke `rake jobs:work` which will start working off jobs. You can
cancel the rake task with `CTRL-C`.

If you want to just run all available jobs and exit you can use `rake jobs:workoff`

Work off queues by setting the `QUEUE` or `QUEUES` environment variable.

```
QUEUE=tracking rake jobs:work
QUEUES=mailers,tasks rake jobs:work
```

---

#### **A couple more things:**

1. You should always specify which queues to run.
2. You'll also need to ensure the script is run when your app is deployed. (You can do this with Capistrano, Mina, Foreman, upstart and many other ways.)

Answer (score 0):

Miad is correct, [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is likely what you are looking for, unless you are literally talking about using the [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem, which is another queue adapter. Sidekiq is basically a queue adapter that connects Rails' [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) with [Redis](http://redis.io/). You can create Jobs with ActiveJob and kick them off by calling the perform method from your Job class. This will queue them in a Sidekiq queue, pass them to redis, and they will be performed asynchronously. Your code might look something like this:
in `app/jobs/your_job.rb`

```
class YourJob < ActiveJob::Base
  #specify the name of your queue
  queue_as :the_queue

  # you must define perform, this is where the async magic happens
  def perform(something)
   do_stuff_to(something)
  end
end
```

in `app/models/place_where_job_is_kicked_off.rb`

```
class PlaceWhereJobIsKickedOff

  def do_the_jobs
    Something.all.each do |something|
      # enqueue your jobs to be performed as soon as the queueing system is free. The queue size is set in your sidekiq.yml
      # each job will be enqueued and run asynchronously, so watch out for race conditions.
      YourJob.perfom_later(something)
    end
  end
end
```

in `app/config/enviroments/production.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do
 #other production configs...

 #set the ActiveJob queue adapter to sidekiq
 config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

 #other production configs...
end
```

in `app/config/sidekiq.yml`

```
:verbose: true
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: log/sidekiq.log
# 5 jobs can run asynchronously simultaneously
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
    # queue names go here [name, size]
  - [the_queue, 5]
```

**Make sure that your have Redis installed and running on your production server, and sidekiq is running**. After adding the sidekiq gem to gemfile, and bundle installing, run:

`sidekiq -C path/to/sidekiq.yml -d (-e environment)`

this will start sidekiq as daemon process.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is `sidekiq` gem. it is used in order to run jobs asynchronously.
http://sidekiq.org